# Error in Converting Python Script to Executable: FileNotFoundError When Running Facial Landmark Detection and Mouse Control Code

Tags: python, opencv, pyinstaller, mediapipe

I've been working on a Python script that utilizes OpenCV, MediaPipe, and PyAutoGUI libraries to perform facial landmark detection and control the mouse cursor based on detected landmarks. The script works perfectly when executed as a Python script, but I've encountered an issue when trying to convert it into an executable (.exe) file.

**Problem:**
Upon running the executable, I'm encountering the following error traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "threading.py", line 1016, in _bootstrap_inner
  File "threading.py", line 953, in run
  File "main.py", line 10, in mouse
  File "mediapipe\python\solutions\face_mesh.py", line 95, in __init__
  File "mediapipe\python\solution_base.py", line 264, in __init__
FileNotFoundError: The path does not exist.
[7464] Failed to execute script 'eyeMouse' due to unhandled exception
```

**Here is my Code:**

```
import cv2
import mediapipe as mp
import pyautogui
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
face_mesh = mp.solutions.face_mesh.FaceMesh(refine_landmarks=True)
screen_w, screen_h = pyautogui.size()
while True:
    _, frame = cam.read()
    frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)
    rgb_frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    output = face_mesh.process(rgb_frame)
    landmark_points = output.multi_face_landmarks
    frame_h, frame_w, _ = frame.shape
    if landmark_points:
        landmarks = landmark_points[0].landmark
        for id, landmark in enumerate(landmarks[474:478]):
            x = int(landmark.x * frame_w)
            y = int(landmark.y * frame_h)
            cv2.circle(frame, (x, y), 3, (0, 255, 0))
            if id == 1:
                screen_x = screen_w * landmark.x
                screen_y = screen_h * landmark.y
                pyautogui.moveTo(screen_x, screen_y)
        left = [landmarks[145], landmarks[159]]
        for landmark in left:
            x = int(landmark.x * frame_w)
            y = int(landmark.y * frame_h)
            cv2.circle(frame, (x, y), 3, (0, 255, 255))
        if (left[0].y - left[1].y) < 0.004:
            pyautogui.click()
            pyautogui.sleep(1)
    cv2.imshow('Eye Controlled Mouse', frame)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```